# How to program for a older version of OS X in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I currently have Mac OSX 10.7.5 (Lion) running on my computer, along with Xcode 4.5.1. I have made a app that works on my computer and should also work on Mountain Lion, but everyone I know and would like giving it to have either OSX 10.5.8 or 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard). Is there any way I could convert my application so that it is compatable on Snow Leopard?
(And yes, I have already tried changing the deployment target).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set for backward compatibility as changing few settings

1. Set the Base SDK to Current version of Mac (ex. 10.7) Set the
2. Set the Deployment SDK to older version (ex.1.4)

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would I change these things?

Comment: @user1936689, Of course. You may have to re-write your app slightly. Some API's may not be available.

Comment: Does it matter if my app uses fullscreen?

Comment: Is any difficulty in fullscreen?

Comment: When I try to open the app on the old computer, it says it quit unexpectedly

Comment: No. It just says "Ignore" "Report..." and "Reopen"

Comment: what about log in console?

Comment: Its not on my computer like I said. There is no console.

Comment: open spotlight and type console. In mac os there is an application called console, that is used to log many things.

Comment: If you're talking about the "full screen" API's, [these came in with MacOS 10.7](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html) and these absolutely ***WILL NOT*** work on 10.5.8 or 10.6.